# ggplot2: position text at the bottom of a bar (using position_dodge)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data.frame which I am using to plot a barplot with mean values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Some sample data
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(grp = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "Total"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
                 value = runif(n = n, min = 1, max = 5),
                 item = sample(c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3"), size = n, replace = TRUE))

# Barplot
df %>% 
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, group = grp, y = mean, fill = grp)) +
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, 2)), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), size = 4) +
    geom_text(aes(label = n), position = ??, size = 4)
```

Additionally, I would like to add the number of cases (per bar) at the bottom of the bar (or here on the left side as the coordinates are flipped). What do I have to use for the `position`-argument of `geom_text()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `y = 0` in your aesthetic to add the labels at the bottom of your bars with `position_dodge` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(item, grp) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = item, group = grp, y = mean, fill = grp)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, 2)), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), size = 4) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n, y = 0), position = position_dodge(0.9),
            size = 4)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'item'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>